# How to ignore spaces only for dynamic content while forming an regular expression to compare two sentences?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a sentence, and I need to compare it with customer send message and return whether it has been passed or failed.
Sentence contains {#val#}, which can be replaced by any values in the customer send messages. Condition here is in place of {#val#} in a sentence  => Customer message can contain anything within the limit of 5.
{#val#} is the dynamic content. Other part of the messages are static content.
In static content of the customer message, we can ignore the space and compare with the sentence defined.

But in dynamic content of the customer send messages,({#val#}) spaces should be considered. For example, sentence contains {#val#}{#val#} and in customer msg it should be replaced by nehradutta not nehra space dutta since 2 {#val#}{#val#}s are continuosly put up in the defined sentence.

```
 var sentence = "Hi {#val#}, Thank you {#val#} {#val#} for visting us"

var customermsg = "Hi asz, Thank you shaky dutta for visting us" //Should Pass as sentence and customer msg  are matching 

var customermsg1 = "Hiasz, Thank you shaky dutta forvisting   us" //Should Pass as sentence and customer msg  are matching ( Ignoring the space in static portion ) 

var customermsg2 = "Hi asz, Thank you nehra      dutta for visting us" //Should Fail since there is lot of space between the dynamic content {#val#} => (nehra     dutta) places.  Should contain single space since the sentence has {#val#}space{#val#}.
```

I need to form a regular expression, which would avoid spaces while comparing static content and include spaces while comparing dynamic content.

Currently my code is below replacing all the spaces and comparing.

```
var separators = ['#val#','#VAL#','#vaL#','#vAl#','#Val#'];
var regexStr = sentence.replace(/[\ ]/g,''); 
var customermsg = customermsg.replace(/[\ ]/g,'');
separators.forEach(str => { 
   regexStr = regexStr.replace(new RegExp(str, 'g'), '.{0,5}')  
}) 
var regex = new RegExp(`^${regexStr }$`,"i")
 if (!customermsg.match(regex))       
   Status = "Fail" 
 else    
   Status = "Pass"
```

Kindly help me on this as I'm new to regular expression

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Hi Sir, Could you please help me with this, I have taken this from one of your previously answered question, Could you please once have a look at it ?

Comment: @sai pls helpdf

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I need to omit the spaces while comparing the sentence with customer msgs. In the place of {#val#} in the sentence, customer msg can pass anything within the limit of 5 chars. But the check here is, if two or more {#val} {#val#} comes together with single space or without space in the customer msg, we need to include that spaces while comparing. Static content spaces can differ from sentence & customermsg, still it should be passed, but for dynamic content exact spaces should be there.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Is it understandable? Could you please help me on this?

Comment: In case this helps, since you want one RegEx to pass your three tests - this one does : `Hi[ ]?(\w+),[ ]*Thank[ ]*you[ ]?(\w+)[ ]?(\w)+[ ]?for[ ]*visting[ ]*us`. 

It's obviously not what you are looking to achieve. I have been trying to imagine the underlying problem behind your question, and I'm confident there are many efficient ways to solve whatever it is, but I don't know which one to share since I'm unsure of your underlying goal. You keep on saying you "need to omit spaces"; tell us more about **why?**! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use two regexes because of the complexity of the conditions but here is my answer.

I explained the regex in comments

```js
const separator = '{#val#}'; // This is what is used to declare dynamic content

const staticSpace = new RegExp(`(?=[^.\\s*${separator}\\s*.])(\\s|.{0})`, 'i');
// This regex called staticSpace, is for those the spacing between static content, that you said should be ignored.

const dynamicSpace = new RegExp(`\\s*(${separator})\\s*`, 'gi');
// This regex called dynamicSpace, is for the possible spacing between static content and dynamic content, that you said shouldn't be too long, so I figured only one space after a dynamic word is alright.
// The \s* is used to mark any amount of space
// The (${seperator}) will input the seperator variable, this part is crucial cus that's how dynamic content would be marked.
// Then the last \s* with the same use to the first


const sentence = "Hi {#val#}, Thank you {#val#} {#val#} for visting us"; // Template for the messages
let customerMessages = ["Hi asz, Thank you shaky dutta for visting us", "Hiasz, Thank you shaky dutta forvisting   us", "Hi asz, Thank you nehra      dutta for visting us"]; // All the customerMessages

let regex = new RegExp(`^${[].concat.apply([], sentence.split(staticSpace).map(a => a.includes(separator) ? a : a.split(/.{0}|\s/))).filter(e => /\S/.test(e)).join('\\s*').replace(dynamicSpace, '\\s?$1\\s?').replace(new RegExp(separator, 'gi'), '[.\\S]{0,5}')}$`, 'i');
// Firstly, I split the template to the static content to ensure that static spacing is ignored
// Then I replaced all the dynamicSpace with \s?1\s? which is just for one space before and after the seperator
// Then all the extra spacing, this would be static content spacing which you said can be as long as it wants and I replaced it with \s* which matches 0 or as many as possible because of static content that may be joined together
// Finally, I used the seperator to match the dynamic content placeholders. [.\\S]{0,5}, this regex matches any character except a space, with a limit of 5 characters. Because you said that the dynamic content should not be longer than 5 characters
// I passed the flag i to most of the replacements because of case-insensitivity. You woulnd't have to define the same seperator in different cases now

console.log(customerMessages.map(message => ({
  message,
  state: regex.test(message) ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'
})));
// logging out the result
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var separators = ["#val#", "#VAL#", "#vaL#", "#vAl#", "#Val#"];
let sentence = "Hi {#VAL#}, Thank you {#val#} {#val#} for visting us";
// make all spaces optional. Except "} {".
regexString = sentence.replace(/(^|.)\s($|.)/g, (x, g1, g2) => (x == "} {" ? x : g1 + "\\s?" + g2));
// turn separators into .{0,5}
separators.forEach((str) => {
    regexString = regexString.replace(new RegExp(`{${str}}`, "g"), ".{0,5}");
});
// input
var customermsg = "Hi asz, Thank you nehra dutta for visting us"; //Should Pass
var customermsg1 = "Hiasz, Thank you nehra dutta forvisting us"; //Should Pass
var customermsg2 = "Hi asz, Thank you nehradutta for visting us"; //Should Fail

let regex = RegExp("^" + regexString + "$");

console.log("REGEX ==>", regex);
console.log(regex.test(customermsg) ? "Pass" : "Fail", "==>", customermsg);
console.log(regex.test(customermsg1) ? "Pass" : "Fail", "==>", customermsg1);
console.log(regex.test(customermsg2) ? "Pass" : "Fail", "==>", customermsg2);
```

Comment: This is not working for a scenario like if customer msg is Hiasz, Tha nk you nehra Dutta for visting us". If the space is given between Tha nk , it should pass, since static content spaces are ignored... Kindly help. @AndreMarasca